# Excel Pivot - Calculate average for values > XX

Tags: excel, pivot, calculated-field

Data table simplified - read only:

```html
<table border=1>
<tr><th>Date</th><th>Hours</th></tr>
<tr><td>Jan. 1</td><td>6.5</td></tr>
<tr><td>Jan. 2</td><td>8.5</td></tr>
<tr><td>Jan. 3</td><td>7.5</td></tr>
<tr><td>Jan. 4</td><td>9.0</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now I would like a pivot table that can calculate the average number of hours - only taking into account the days where the number of hours are > 8.0. Ie. for the above data the pivot should return 8.75.

I've tried with calculated field: =If(Hours > 8, Hours, NULL) - or blanks instead of null or similar.

Please help.

Comment: Why not use a slicer?

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/pivottable-conditional-average/80f0cf1e-5ec2-4df2-a5e4-272da48b20e7

Comment: @MichalRosa: As mentioned the data is read only, which means I can't convert it to a "Table" and so can't use PowerPivot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a Pivot table. Just use `=AverageIf([Range of Hours],">8")`

Edit:

To achieve through Pivot Table, I can only think of using "measure". But it could be quite slow for 120k rows as the `Filter()` function need to go through each row one by one.

1. create a the Pivot Table with the checkbox "Add this data to the Data Model" clicked;
2. Right-click on the "Range" (or the table name if your data is a table) in the Field List and choose "Add Measure"
3. Enter the measure's info and use `=SUMX(Range, if(Range[Hour]>8, Range[Hour],0))/ COUNTROWS(FILTER(ALL(Range), Range[Hour]>8))` as formula (replace "Range" with Table name if source data is a table). And click "OK".

Then, you can use this measure to get the average value you want.

Comment: As mentioned the data shown is very simplified. In reality the dataset consists of 30 columns and 120.000 rows. And since I need to extract a lot of different numbers with different conditions, the easiest thing is to do it with 1 technology, which is Pivot.
So even though your suggestion gives the right answer it is not a viable option.
It has to be Pivot.